# Node JS multliple promises chaining

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have node JS api server and I'm having issues with correct chaining of the Promises:

```
app.post(
  "/api/tasks",
  async function (_req, res) {

    const newArray = [{ MyTasks: [] }];
    const getOne = async (owner, taskID) => {
      return await getOneDocument(owner, taskID).then((result) => {
        console.log("get one doc", result);
        return result;
      });
    };
// first promise
    let toApproveTasks = await getToApproveTasks(_req.body.userID);
    console.log("1", toApproveTasks);

    // loop trough the result of 1st promise and run async function for each
    const arrayToDoc = async (array) => {
      array.TasksToApprove.forEach(async (element) => {
        let objToPush = await getOne(element.Owner, element.TaskID);
        console.log("1.5", objToPush);
        newArray.MyTasks.push(objToPush);
      });
    };
    // second promise
    await arrayToDoc(toApproveTasks);
    console.log("2", newArray);
// third promise
    let finalResult = await parseCosmosOutput(newArray);
    console.log("3", finalResult);

    res.status(200).send(finalResult);
  }
);
```

What I get in console is :

- 1 [Object] - all good
- 2. Emppty Array
- 3. Empty Array
- get one doc {object} - all good
- 1.5 {object} - all good

How would I make sure when I loop over result of 1st promise my code awaits async function and pushes to newArray results ?

Comment: `.forEach` is **not** promise-aware. Also the mix of `async`/`await` and `.then` is only adding to the confusion.

Comment: Replace your `forEach` with `for (const element of array.TasksToApprove) {}`

Comment: It also depends on whether you want to evaluate the elements of the array one after another (await each time in a loop), or don't care about the specific order as long as every one of them finishes (use `map` and `Promise.all`).

Comment: `const newArray = [{ MyTasks: [] }];` or `newArray.MyTasks` looks like a mistake, though, as the key `MyTasks` is found in `newArray[0]`, not within `newArray` itself.

Comment: As @jonrsharpe said, forEach is not a solution for your "await", why ?
check this [doc](https://www.hacksparrow.com/javascript/foreach-in-promise-async-function.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use For..of instead of forEach inside arrayToDoc function

E.g

```
const arrayToDoc = async (array) => {
    for(let element of array.TasksToApprove){
        let objToPush = await getOne(element.Owner, element.TaskID);
        console.log("1.5", objToPush);
        newArray.MyTasks.push(objToPush);
    }
};
```

Comment: Here is a tip, if you use `for of`, think about using `const` instead.  Unless you really do want to change the element inside the loop.  `for of` is not like a normal `for`, were your index will indeed want to be a `let`.  Your `objToPush` also would benefit from `const`..  Might seem trivial, but using `let` / `const` correctly can prevent bugs, especially in larger apps.